# How to load content with dojo?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

I'm writing a single page website using dojo. Tutorials describe how to use dojo/request for making ajax requests. I can simply make request, receive html content and insert it into a content panel (div element). This is also demonstrated in the samples.

When I start to load real content with some desired functionality, I need to also add a script element to the content which is requested by an ajax call. The problem is that the script received with ajax content is not executed.

I tried using `contentNode.innerHTML = data;` and also `domConstruct.place(data, contentNode, "only");`
In both cases content is shown but the scripts inside the content is not executed.

As I understand there's also a `dijit.layout.ContentPane` which is more suitable for loading content on design time, not runtime.

I cannot execute the script before the content is loaded, because in every page there are some elements which I need to process, and they are simple not available when the main page is loaded. For example, I need to change form submission behavior.

So what can I do to make the loaded script executed?

Answer (score 1):

There is a `dojox.layout.ContentPane` that provides the ability to execute scripts from the loaded content.

See the official documentation [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/layout/ContentPane.html). It excplicitly addresses your use case

> If you need to execute JavaScript inside your content panes, use
>   dojox/layout/ContentPane instead of dijit/layout/ContentPane and set
>   executeScripts=”true”. Actually executeScripts defaults to “true” but
>   might be a visual cue down the road as to why you are using
>   dojox/layout/ContentPane.

Comment: However, one should never be sending scripts from the server to execute in response to an Ajax request like this. The server should provide *data*, and the client should then respond to and process the data using code that has already been loaded.

Comment: @CSnover So what is the proper way to do that? I guess you are not suggesting that I write a separate function for every link I have in the page right? Every click results with loading some content and scripts must be executed for example for calendar textboxes, for submit handling, etc...

Comment: @Lucas: I already mentioned that ContentPane is not suitable for changing the content several times, it's designed for loading certain content once after the page load. If you don't agree, can you be more specific?

Comment: You can change the content of a `dojox.layout.ContentPane` by calling `pane.set("href", url)`.  This returns a `Deferred`.  I used this functionality back in Dojo 1.6, but I'm not sure how it may have changed in later versions.  It is not trivial to make this kind of loading robust.  In my case, I had to leverage the `scriptHasHooks` functionality to get a reference to the containing `dojox.layout.ContentPane` so that the loaded content's scripts could fire custom events, i.e. onContentComplete, onContentParseError, etc.

Comment: @rosencreuz If your form definitions change dynamically on every click, then you would use a form builder on the client…but I suspect they don’t, and what you should be doing is using a StackContainer or similar that contains various view widgets with all your forms and things precomposed, switch between them, and request data from the server and place them into the precomposed views as needed.